# Comparing char with integer

Tags: c, char, comparison

I am getting an error when compiling the following

```
char *token;
...
if(token == 'x')
{
    ...
}
```

The error I am getting is: comparison between pointer and integer. How does this work and how do I fix it?

Comment: By dereferencing the pointer `if(*token == 'x')`

Comment: Note that the integer the compiler refers to is `'x'`. Character literals (enclosed by single quotes) have type `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `token` isn't a `char`, it's a pointer to a `char`. Change this

```
if(token == 'x')
```

to

```
if(*token == 'x')
```

Answer (score 1):

In C integer character constants have type `int`.

(C Standard, 6.4.4.4 Character constants)

> 10 An integer character constant has type int.

So in this expression

```
token == 'x'
```

pointer token defined as

```
char *token;
```

is compared with integer constant 'x'. The compiler does not know how to compare them and issues the error.

I think you wanted to compare the object pointed to by pointer token with the integer constant that is

```
if( *token == 'x')
```

Take into account that token shall be assigned a valid address.